# pd.where() gives TypeError: where() got multiple values for argument 'other' when there is only on value

Tags: python, pandas

I've read the docs,

(https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

When I use the below, all is fine and the code works perfectly:

```
df['c06new']='not_women_gathered'
df[c06new].where(f1 & f2,"women_gathered",inplace=True)
(df[c06new]=='women_gathered').sum()
```

However, if I use,

```
df.where(f1 & f2,"women_gathered", other='not',inplace=True)
```

I get: `TypeError: where() got multiple values for argument 'other'`

*Why is this?*

Comment: `df.where` takes 1st argument as condition and 2nd argument as other value when condition is false.  The original value is taken when condition is True.  So with the first syntax, "women_gathered" is assigned when condition is not met. In the 2nd line, you have "women_gathered" for the 2nd argument which is for `other` and you have another named `other` argument, resulting in the error.  If you want to have a function that can assign a new value both for true and false, check out `np.where`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is producing an error because you're supplying other as a positional argument, but also as a keyword. For example, this gives us your error, TypeError: where() got multiple values for argument 'other.'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(10)})
df.where(df > 5, 10, other=12)
```

However, these two examples give the expected result.

```
df.where(df > 5, other=12)
df.where(df > 5, 12)
```

Output:

```
A
0   12
1   12
2   12
3   12
4   12
5   12
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
```

As suggested by Emma, you might be looking for [np.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
df['A'] = np.where(df > 5, 99, 12)
```

Output on original df:

```
A
0   12
1   12
2   12
3   12
4   12
5   12
6   99
7   99
8   99
9   99
```